# Can I determine changes in data stored in Postgresql column of type jsonb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

After associating paper trail gem with a Rails model that has one of the columns of data type jsonb (using Postgresql), the changeset or changes methods on paper trail version does not return the changes. Is there a way to configure/override paper tail gem to determine changes in column of type jsonb?

I have tried the type of object column in versions table from text to jsonb but that did not help. The `changes` method is always returning an empty hash.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, will update if I find anything

Comment: PT does not have any tests that cover this situation. So, you may be the first people to need this feature. We're not currently accepting issues, but PRs are welcome.